# Enable DEBUG Message during run time

Tags: c, linux

I want to enable "printf("macro MESSAGE is %d\n",MESSAGE);" during run time.  For example , if i give argument 10 in run time, it should print the message. if it is not given, it should not print this message.Is it possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MESSAGE 10

int foo;
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        foo = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("foo is %d\n", foo);

#if MESSAGE==foo
        printf("macro MESSAGE is %d\n",MESSAGE);
#endif
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with an `if` check?

Comment: The preprocessor can not use the runtime value.

Comment: or you meant compile time...then it's a different ball game.

Comment: The `#if MESSAGE == foo` is evaluated by the preprocessor at compile time.  At compile time, `foo` is not defined, so it is treated as 0, and the condition fails.  You need to defer the test to runtime, so write `if (foo == MESSAGE)` before the `printf()` and omit the `#endif`.

Comment: In order to enable printf macro you can use preprocesser that is #ifdef debug.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer and how is that runtime?

Comment: Use assert like `assert(MESSAGE!=foo || printf("macro MESSAGE is %d\n",MESSAGE));`

Comment: When using assert  Compiling with compile option `-DNDEBUG` will delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can define a macro conditionally based on a preprocessor macro to control in *compile time* what the definition of the macro is:

```
#if DEBUGGING
#define debug(format, ...) fprintf(stderr, format, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define debug(format, ...) ()
#endif
```

The `debug` macro itself is actually an example in [GCC's manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html).

Or, we could make a similar function that checks in *run time* the value of some variable:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int debugging = 10;
void debug(int msglevel, const char *fmt, ...)
{  
    if (debugging < msglevel) return;
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, va);
    va_end(va);
}
...
debug(10, "Error: %s\n", "some explanation");
```

A full function makes it easier to do a greater than comparison for the verbosity level. Of course we could still have an alternate definition of r the function on compile time to fully disable it. For the varargs, see the [va_arg(3) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg).